# Multiple image preview from input to different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i upload multiple images from inputs into separate divs? So user can upload images from their computer and they will appear in different divs

html

```
<form id="form" runat="server">
    <input type='file' class="img" />
    <input type='file' class="img" />
    <input type='file' class="img" />
</form>  

<div>
  <img class="image" src="#" alt="image 1" /> 
</div>
<div>
  <img class="image" src="#" alt="image 2" /> 
</div>
<div>
  <img class="image" src="#" alt="image 3" /> 
</div>
```

jquery

```
  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".img").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: id should be unique use class instead

Comment: still wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var div_id  = $(input).attr('set-to');
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#'+div_id).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".img").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```css
img{
  height : 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" runat="server">
    <input type='file' class="img" set-to="div1" />
    <input type='file' class="img" set-to="div2" />
    <input type='file' class="img" set-to="div3" />
</form>  

<div>
  <img class="image" id="div1" src="#" alt="image 1" /> 
</div>
<div>
  <img class="image" id="div2" src="#" alt="image 2" /> 
</div>
<div>
  <img class="image" id="div3" src="#" alt="image 3" /> 
</div>
```

Please check this code might help you out.
I have given the **Div Id** as **set-to** attribute for the **Input Image Tag** and before adding the image value to div am setting the value of div.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much :) this is perfect :)